# Photoshop doesn't have Text on shape Tool

Tags: photoshop

I watch this tutorial [Text on shape tool photoshop elements text shape infopuppet Part II](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_912645&feature=iv&src_vid=C7WHfYTuIL8&v=zeGgBo7uZKI) and I see him use Text on Shape Tool. and I want to use it but in my photoshop cs6 doesn't have Text on Shape Tool.

Why my photoshop doesn't have Text on Shape Tool and How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your shape. Grab the text tool and click directly on the shape and you can now begin to type inside. Remember, don't drag the text tool, just click on the shape with the Text Tool selected. That should work.